# How to launch tel:12345678 link in softphone from FileMaker?

Tags: filemaker

I am trying to make «click-to-call» feature in my FileMaker 11 database on Mac OS X 10.9.x:

```
Open URL [ "tel:" & $phonenumber ]
```

But this code only activates browser and and call to the telephone is not done. What I make wrong?

i am using Tlphn.com softphone and links like tel:12345678 opens properly from html pages.

Comment: Are you opening it on the desktop or in FileMaker Go? I believe the `tel` prefix only works in go.

Comment: I am opening on Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is: use AppleScript, Luke.

```
tell application "System Events" 
    open location "tel:12345678" 
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you're using is correct, it's just the version of FileMaker you're on that's causing the problem for you.

To use the `tel` url, you need to be on a device that has direct access to a phone. With FileMaker Go running on an iphone, you can open your `tel` url and Go knows to pass that to the phone application. Because FileMaker Pro and Pro Advanced run from a desktop, which has no inherently attached phone, they're not built to open a tell url and pass it to a phone (because what phone would it pass the call to?).

You could potentially make a call from your desktop if you connected your computer and FileMaker Pro to a phone (like a voice over IP phone).

It's likely that the easiest way of making a call from FileMaker Pro on your desktop is to have FileMaker place the call via Skype. I did a quick search and found [This article](http://hbase.net/2013/09/03/dialing-telephone-numbers-using-skypeout-from-filemaker-pro/) that explains how to make a skype call from FileMaker Pro. I have not tried this before so I don't know if it works or not, but glancing through it the process makes sense.

Hope this helps!